# Free & libre software MIDI sequencer

Tags: windows, gratis, open-source

Not at all for lazyness, I'll be brief to respect your time:
I need a

free=0$ no price

libre/permissive license that allows me to not have time or usage limits, no big truncation of features, not "freemium". I had to tag this with "open source" since [this desicion.](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17/tags-for-free-software-and-free-software)

[music sequencer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_sequencer) with MIDI full compatibility (indeed MIDI is the only thing I will do with it, audio management not needed)

Those are all the requirements needed, to be brief I don't write walls of useless text, also I'm sure other people will need similar software like me, anyone who does "computer music" (which is not electronic music, but actually almost ALL MUSIC uses software today) will need a sequencer, probably a midi one since it's a standard, and surely will like to try a free one and libre.

Answer (score 1):

There are different types/styles of music sequencers out there, each having its own specialties. Some mature ones, all under the GPL license, are, e.g.,

- [Ardour](http://ardour.org/) - a full-fledged digital audio workstation (DAW) with MIDI support (Linux, Windows, macOS)
- [Frinika](http://www.frinika.com) - another DAW with MIDI support (Linux, Windows, macOS)
- [LMMS](https://lmms.io/) - an [FL Studio](https://www.image-line.com/flstudio/) (formerly *Fruity Loops*) style sequencer (Linux, Windows, macOS)
- [Hydrogen](http://www.hydrogen-music.org) - A specialized drum sequencer that also follows the FL Studio approach (Linux, Windows, macOS)
- [MuseScore](https://musescore.org) - a scorewriting software that supports MIDI playback (Linux, Windows, macOS)
- [seq24](http://filter24.org/seq24/) - a piano-roll style MIDI-only sequencer (Linux, Windows)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Tracktion 6? It's free
https://www.tracktion.com/products/t6-daw

and you can follow these tutorials on youtube about Tracktion 6:
https://www.youtube.com/user/lilacwriter/search?query=T6